# R: How to do fastest replacement in R?

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I have a input dataframe like this (the real one is very large, so I want to do it faster):

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=c(1:5), B=c(5:9), C=c(9:13))

  A B  C
1 1 5  9
2 2 6 10
3 3 7 11
4 4 8 12
5 5 9 13
```

I have a dataframe with replacement code like this (the entries here maybe more than df1):

```
df2 <- data.frame(X=c(1:15), Y=c(101:115))

    X   Y
1   1 101
2   2 102
3   3 103
4   4 104
5   5 105
6   6 106
7   7 107
8   8 108
9   9 109
10 10 110
11 11 111
12 12 112
13 13 113
14 14 114
15 15 115
```

By matching df2$X with value in df1$A and df1$B, I want to get a new_df1 by replace df1$A and df1$B with the corresponding values in df2$Y, i.e. resulting this new_df1

```
  A    B    C
1 101  105  9
2 102  106 10
3 103  107 11
4 104  108 12
5 105  109 13
```

Could you mind to give me some guidance how to do it faster in R, as my dataframe is very large?  Many thanks.

Comment: It's going to be tough to suggest a *faster* way to do this unless we know how you've already tried to do it and found it to be too slow. Also, can we assume that the values in df2$X are always in order as they are in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's supereasy! You just need to get the proper offsets in the array.

So for instance, to get the Y column of `df2` corresponding to the values in the A column of `df1` you'll write `df2$Y[df1$A]`

Hence, your code will be:

```
df_new <- data.frame("A" = df2$Y[df1$A], "B" = df2$Y[df1$B], "C" = df1$C)
```

Comment: However, be aware that this approach assumes that df2 is ordered by X and that X must equal the row number of every single row. You could verify this by typing `all(df2$X == 1:nrows(df2))`. If this is not true, you should look into the `match`-function.

Comment: @Thilo: from the example data he gave I thought that was the case, but you make a very good point. Also, `which` may be of use.

Comment: @nico: I probably would have given the same answer you did. My comment was partly intended to guide any further reader who uses your solution without thinking about the preconditions.

Answer (score 2):

As Thilo mentioned Nico's answer assumes that `df2` is ordered by `X` and `X` contains every integer 1,2,3....

I would prefer to use `match()` as a more general case:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=c(1:5), B=c(5:9), C=c(9:13))
df2 <- data.frame(X=c(1:15), Y=c(101:115))

new_df1 <- df1

new_df1$A <- df2$Y[match(df1$A,df2$X)]
new_df1$B <- df2$Y[match(df1$B,df2$X)]
    A   B  C
1 101 105  9
2 102 106 10
3 103 107 11
4 104 108 12
5 105 109 13
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another (one-liner) way of doing it.

```
> with(c(df2,df1),data.frame(A = Y[match(A,X)],B = Y[match(B,X)],C))
    A   B  C
1 101 105  9
2 102 106 10
3 103 107 11
4 104 108 12
5 105 109 13
```

However I am not sure whether it will be faster than the other suggestions